# How to calculate total elements in the list

Tags: r

I have a list.

```
x <- list(1:3, 4:5, 6:9)

> x
#[[1]]
#[1] 1 2 3

#[[2]]
#[1] 4 5

#[[3]]
#[1] 6 7 8 9
```

I need to find the total elements in the list which is 9 in this case. By using `length(x)` i get output as 3. I am sure there must be something simple solution to this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `length(unlist(x))`?

Comment: Ohh..yes! This was so stupid of me. Thanks @Pascal

Comment: @Pascal unless this is a dupe, please post so we can close this and move on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a combination of `length` and `unlist`.

```
x <- list(1:3, 4:5, 6:9)
length(unlist(x))
# [1] 9
```